# RPostgresql executing a function that returns void

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I have a code that looks like this:

```
con <- connect_to_my_postgres_database()

dbClearResult(dbExecute(con, "select function_that_returns_void()")

postgresqlCloseConnection(con)
```

This is yielding the error:

```
Condition: RPosgreSQL warning: unrecognized PostgreSQL field type void (id:2278) in column 0
NULL
Error in postgresqlCloseConnection(con) :
  connection has pending rows (close open results set first)
Execution halted
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Not sure, but fwiw: `dbExecute` already ensures the `dbClearResult` is called. The return argument from `dbExecute` should be returning an integer, which should (and perhaps _will_, eventually) cause `dbClearResult` to err with `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbClearResult’ for signature ‘"integer"’`. Clearly not your error now, but it will be when you figure out how to get `dbExecute` to not error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I made a table `"create table r2temp (id int)"`, then created a void-returning function `"create function void_fun() returns void as $$ begin update r2temp set id=1 where id=2; end; $$ language plpgsql;"`, and `DBI::dbExecute(con, "select void_fun()")` returns 1, no error. Even wrapping in `dbClearResult` returns the different error I mentioned in my previous comment. Do you know the contents of your `*_void()` function to know what it is doing differently?

Comment: @r2evans try adding a line with `RAISE NOTICE 'Hey r2evans!'` on your function. That's the only thing that could be meaningfully different in my case. Also, I find weird that the function as you describe has a mandatory input but your R snippet does not provide it.

Comment: What mandatory input?

Comment: Still cannot reproduce, unfortunately. `DBI::dbExecute(con, "create table r2temp (id int)"); DBI::dbExecute(con, "create function void_fun() returns void as $$ begin update r2temp set id=1 where id=2; raise notice 'hey r2evans!'; end; $$ language plpgsql;"); DBI::dbExecute(con, "select void_fun()")` returns `1`.

Comment: In case it matters: R-4.3.2; DBI_1.2.1; and postgres version is 13.14.